# ListView with edittexts

Tags: android, listview, focus, android-edittext

I'm working on an android application and I want to implement a listview, each row contents 4 EditTexts.
The main goal is to write in the EditText and then save them in a list.
I met the same problem here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21105
It works perfectly when I click on the three first elements and the end of three, but when I click on the 5th element, for example (if I have 22 items on my list), I lose focus and I have to scroll another time to find the point where I clicked.
I create a Subclass extends from ListView and here my GUI :

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <AutoResizingListView
                android:id="@+id/listViewProduits"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/background_color" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**sub class :**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 *
 */
public class AutoResizingListView extends ListView {
    public AutoResizingListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AutoResizingListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AutoResizingListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void clearChildFocus(View child) {
        super.clearChildFocus(child);
        if (getSelectedItemPosition() != -1 && getItemsCanFocus()) {
            requestFocus();
        }
    }


    @Override public void setAdapter(final ListAdapter adapter) {
        super.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
            @Override public void onChanged() {
                setHeight();
            }
        });

        setHeight();
    }

    private void setHeight() {
        ListAdapter adapter = getAdapter();
        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = adapter.getView(i, null, this);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = this.getLayoutParams();
        int dividerHeights = getDividerHeight() * (adapter.getCount() == 0 ? 0 : adapter.getCount() - 1);
        params.height = totalHeight + dividerHeights;
        setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: If you know how many textView you will be using a listview is not the ony solution. You can also put a layout in the .xml and add textview programmatically at run time =)

Comment: We don' know how many Edittexts we will be using. I did what u said but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
       ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourlistview);
     String[] from = new String[] {"col_1","col_2","col_3","col_4"};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ed_item1, R.id.ed_item2, R.id.ed_item3, R.id.ed_item4 };

        // prepare the list of all records
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
       int cnt=1;
        for(int i = 0; i < seleced_item.length(); i++){
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("col_1","");
            map.put("col_2","" );
            map.put("col_3","");
            map.put("col_4","");

            }
            fillMaps.add(map);
            cnt++;
        }

        // fill in the grid_item layout contains edit boxes with linear layout. 
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.Edit_view, from, to);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In the grid_item layout you can set the request focus on each edit text element.

Comment: Thanks for ur quick response, i need to do a getview because i have to store each value in a each editext in an object. Do you want the whole code?